# How to select policy of block placement in the DataNode?

Tags: hadoop, block, hdfs

If the block replication is 3 in my hadoop cluster,and every DataNode has 3 ${dfs.data.dir} directories. When the DataNode is choosed to storage block, the block is storage in all 3 direcoties or one of them?

If the answer is latter, how to choose a ${dfs.data.dir} directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right directory is chosen on round robin manner when the block arrives to the datanode. You can alter this behavior by changing dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy to org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy, then the right directory would be chosen based on the space available in them (refer to configurations here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

Comment: Thank you. Is dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy used by Hadoop 2 and latter version？In the hdfs-default.xml of hadoop 1.2.1,there isn't this property,right?

Comment: Here's the ticket in JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1804 - fixed since Hadoop 2.1.0+

Comment: Is am I right about policy of block placement in the DataNode(how to select ${dfs.data.dir} directoires) in hadoop 1.2.1 version?

Comment: Here's release notes for Hadoop 1.2.1: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/releasenotes.html You won't find HDFS-1804 there which means this fix is not part of Hadoop 1.2.1 and you won't be able to use anything except by round robin to alter disk placing policy. You should move to Hadoop 2.1.0+