# multiple Datanode directories write operation

Tags: hadoop

iam using hadoop apache 2.7.1 
and i have configured data node directory to have  multiple directories

```
        <property>
                 <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
                 <value>/opt/hadoop/data_dir,file:///hdd/data_dir/</value>
                 <final>true</final>
        </property>
```

according to this configuration writing  file data should happens on both directories 
/opt/hadoop/data_dir and  file:///hdd/data_dir/  with same blocks names and on same sub directories names

but in my cluster this behavior is not happening some times it writes data blocks  to 
local directory /opt/hadoop/data_dir and some times it writes data blocks to

external hard directory `file:///hdd/data_dir`

what could be possible reasons and how to control this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of `dfs.data.dir` is wrong.  Nowhere is this stated:

> **with same blocks names and on same sub directories names**

Files might get replicated but that happens on different **datanodes**, not on the same datanode with different directories.  Also this property `dfs.data.dir` is deprecated and should be `dfs.datanode.data.dir` which has been there since Hadoop 2.

From [hdfs-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

> dfs.datanode.data.dir
>
> Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices.

Comment: what if i don't want to add a new datanode (new machine) and expand current data node storage http://fibrevillage.com/storage/616-how-to-define-multiple-dfs-data-dir-in-hadoop-how-do-they-work

Comment: thanks for the notification about dfs.datanode.data.dir  but even though i edited it the same behavior occured i mean copying data occurs to one directory of the listed directories only what about round robin fashion style

Comment: RE: expand storage, if you want to add more storage, just add another directory entry.  RE: dfs.datanode.data.dir, yes, you're seeing normal behavior.

Comment: but as you see when they define dfs.datanode.data.dir in hdfs-default.xml they mentioned that data will be stored in all named directories but in my situation it is stored in one of the named directories and that's what confused me

Comment: Data is stored in all named directories but it is NOT copied in all directories.

Comment: you mean that one data directory from named directories is chosen to store data and every time this choice is different and that's good because when one directory is full another one will be chosen

Comment: In general, yes.  By default, selection is round-robin.  If your directories are very different in size you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057518/how-to-select-policy-of-block-placement-in-the-datanode